# Delete Laravel file from storage/app/public/photos

Tags: laravel, file

I am trying to delete a file from storage/app/public/photos.
The url that I am getting from the front end is http/IP_Address/app_name/public/storage/photos/file_name. I tried both unlink and File:delete, but doesn't work because, I believe, filepath is not proper. I tried basename and public_path but it doesn't solve it. Any help?

```
$file_path = public_path(basename($fullLinkToPhoto));
if(File::exists($file_path)) File::delete($file_path);
```

**Edit:** Answer below by larabee worked. I used the Storage method. This is my final code. I got the filename from complete photo link using basename and used that in the Storage::delete.

```
$file_name = basename($fullLinkToPhoto);     
if(\Storage::exists('photos/'.$file_name)){
    \Storage::delete('photos/'.$file_name);
}
```

Comment: If your file is stored in `storage/app/public/photos`, use `Storage::delete('public/photos/filename.ext');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three different ways:

> storage/app/public/

by storage:

```
  if(\Storage::exists('photos/picture.png')){
    \Storage::delete('photos/picture.png');
  }
```

by filesystem:

```
 if(\File::exists(public_path('photos/picture.png'))){
    \File::delete(public_path('photos/picture.png'));
}
```

by php

```
if(file_exists(public_path('photos/picture.png'))){
  unlink(public_path('photos/picture.png'));
}
```

You should use the "storage solution".